# Why, if photons have their spin in the same direction of the electrons, the formers will less likely be able to flip the spins of the latters

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, helicity

It's about the Goldhaber experiment, where the exercise I'm trying to solve is:

Photons are filtered according to their helicity thanks to the magnetic field. For a given
magnetic field, the electrons contained in the magnet see all spins flipped to a preferred
direction. When the magnetic field is inverted, all electrons spins are flipped in the
other direction. Considering that photons can have two different helicities and can
interact with electrons to change their quantum states, explain why photons of a given
helicity for a given magnetic field configuration can loose more energy in the magnet
than photons with the other helicity.

The solution states that:
**If the photons have their spin in the same direction of the electrons, the formers will
less likely be able to flip the spins of the latters.** Thus, the photon will have a smaller
probability to interact with the electrons and loose some energy in the magnet. Then
they will have a larger probability to interact with the samarium scatterer. Thus, photons
are filtered according to their helicity, depending of the magnetic field applied (as they
will loose, in average, enough energy to not exitate a samarium atom of the scatterer).

Can someone explain why the bold text holds?

Comment: Remind me, what is the Goldhaber experiment?

Comment: It's the experiment back in 1957 which showed that neutrinos have negative helicity (are left-handed) and anti-neutrinos have positve helicity (are right-handed). Check out this: https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.109.1015